# IFrame on IE11: This content cannot be displayed in a frame - calling same domain

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, browser-security

We have an internal website loading a page in an IFrame. Previously we had accidentally set the IFrame to load the page from the wrong environment which is on a different domain so an internal user experienced the message "this content cannot be displayed in a frame". We quickly figured out it was because the page was on the wrong environment and updated the URL so that the IFrame and its parent were calling pages from the same domain.

The issue is that one of the users who experience the initial issue is still receiving the message "this content cannot be displayed in a frame" and we're not sure why.

We have tried:

- Clearing the browser cache
- Resetting IE to its default settings using `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults`
- Reinstalling IE
- Reproducing the issue on a fresh IE11 VM from Microsoft: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ this was unsuccessful and the IFrame loaded the content.

No one else is experiencing this issue and we're wondering what else can be causing this problem.

Comment: Is there some sort of proxy caching stuff between the browser and your server? Alter the url with some random querystring value and see if it loads.

Comment: @epascarello No, there isn't a proxy caching anything.

Comment: what about `ipconfig /flashdns` on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE and OS is the user using? It sounds like IE still loading the iframe from cache. You could use F12 dev tools at first when visiting the page. In the Network tab, turn on ['Always refresh from server'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/936Mu.png), then refresh the page to see if the iframe loads content.

Or you could give the iframe a random id every time when it loads, then the iframe will be forced to refresh in IE.

You could also try to reset IE according to the steps in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings).